# How can I combine multiple textfields using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I stack multiple textfields like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcmvU.png)? I am trying to replicate this screen.

I've tried creating a Container with rounded borders, with a Column as the child containing multiple textfields. [But the textfields extend past the border of the Container and the margin between them is too big.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDoV9.png)

My code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Administration extends StatefulWidget {
  const Administration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Administration> createState() => _AdministrationState();
}

class _AdministrationState extends State<Administration> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      body: Column(children: [
          CupertinoNavigationBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.chevron_left,
                  size: 23,
                ),
                color: Colors.grey,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }),
            trailing: const Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              size: 30.0,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            middle: const Text('New Event'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15.0),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where are the textfields in your code? please provide the code that is not working as expected, not a skeleton that is irrelevant to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image I see, I created an example for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('sampla app'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: const Color(0xff1c1c1d),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xff4c4c54), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Title',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    height: 0.2,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Location or Video Call',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Adding the image as well for how it looks.

[image]